# Sampling Theorem and Dirac Comb

Tags: sampling, convolution

I am reading "The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing" and trying to understand [Figure 3.5](http://www.dspguide.com/ch3/3.htm) below which is about the sampling theorem and aliasing.

I do not understand the picture of the frequency domain. The signal can be represented as
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x)e^{ixt}dx$$
where $F(x)$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. This represents $f$ with the "frequencies" $e^{ixt}$ and these can have $x$ negative. How then am I suppose to understand Figure 3-5 which shows the frequency domain for only greater than zero and moreover real and not complex.

Also why does the frequency domain of the impulse train have the original frequency spectrum appear flipped half the time? My current understanding is that the repetition comes from something like
$$\mathcal{F^{-1}} \{f(t)\Delta(t)\} = F(x)*\Delta(x)$$
where $\Delta$ is the dirac comb and probably some kind of constant like $2\pi$ is needed in there somewhere. How does the flipping half the time in the frequency domain arise from $F(x)*\Delta(x)$. The image I think for convolution is that $\Delta$ is flipped and as it is moved to the right by $s$ the "area" of $F(x)\Delta(s-x)$ is the value of the convolution at $s$. This would seem to replicate the original spectrum multiple times but without the flipping half the time as shown in Figure 3.5.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should ask the moderators to move this to dsp.SE

Comment: I'm going to migrate this question to the dsp.SE site. There will be a link that appears below the question here that you can follow to the new location of your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $X(f)$ denote the Fourier transform of $x(t)$ where
$$\begin{align*}
X(f) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \exp(-j2\pi ft) \mathrm dt\\
x(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(f) \exp(+j2\pi ft) \mathrm df
\end{align*}$$
which I will denote via $x(t) \leftrightarrow X(f)$.
The following transform pairs will be needed in what follows.
$$\begin{align*}
\delta(t) &\leftrightarrow 1\\
\delta(t-t_0) &\leftrightarrow \exp(-j2\pi f \,t_0)\\
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT) &\leftrightarrow
\frac{1}{T}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(f-\frac{k}{T}\right)\\
\end{align*}$$

Given a signal $x(t)$, its sampled pulse train (at intervals of $T$ seconds) is 
$$x(t) \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT) 
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)\delta(t-nT) 
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nT)\delta(t-nT).$$
Since multiplication in the time domain corresponds to convolution in the
frequency domain, we have
$$\begin{align*}
x(t)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT) &\leftrightarrow
X(f)\circledast\frac{1}{T}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(f-\frac{k}{T}\right)\\
&\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{T}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}
X(f)\circledast\delta\left(f-\frac{k}{T}\right)\\
&\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{T}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(f-w)\delta\left(w-\frac{k}{T}\right) \mathrm dw\\
x(t)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT)
&\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{T}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}
X\left(f-\frac{k}{T}\right) = \hat{X}(f)
\end{align*}$$
Thus, the Fourier transform of the impulse train formed by
sampling $x(t)$ at $T$ second intervals is $\hat{X}(f)$ which
is obtained by repeating $X(f)$ along the $f$ axis at intervals of 
$T^{-1}$ Hz and summing the result.
Furthermore, $\hat{X}(f)$ is a **periodic** function of the frequency
variable $f$ with period $T^{-1}$ Hz.  That is, for all $f$,
$$\hat{X}\left(f + \frac{1}{T}\right) = \hat{X}(f).$$  Note that
all of this holds **regardless of what $X(f)$ is:** $X(f)$ could be
nonzero for all $f$, and the result would still be valid.

Now suppose that $X(f)$ is zero if $f < a$ or $f > b$.  Then,
$\hat{X}(f)$, obtained by repeating $X(f)$ periodically along
the $f$ axis,  is nonzero only in the intervals
$$\ldots, \left[a-\frac{2}{T}, b-\frac{2}{T}\right], 
\left[a-\frac{1}{T}, b-\frac{1}{T}\right],
[a, b] 
\left[a+\frac{1}{T}, b+\frac{1}{T}\right], 
\left[a+\frac{2}{T}, b+\frac{2}{T}\right], 
\ldots
$$
and so if 
$$b -\frac{1}{T} < a \Rightarrow b-a < \frac{1}{T},$$
that is, the *support* $b-a$ of $X(f)$ is smaller than 
the repetition interval $T^{-1}$ Hz, then the repetitions
of $X(f)$ do not overlap.  Indeed as the OP's figures show, 
for a real-valued signal whose spectrum extends from $a = -f_0$
to $b = f_0$ (support of $X(f)$ is of length $2f_0$), sampling 
$x(t)$ at intervals of $T = (3f_0)^{-1}$ (and thus repeating $X(f)$ at
intervals of $3f_0$ Hz on the frequency axis)
leads to no overlap while sampling $x(t)$ at intervals of
$T = (1.5f_0)^{-1}$ leads to overlap of the repetitions
of $X(f)$.

Finally, the OP asks about negative frequencies and the
interpretation of the pictures which show positive frequencies
only.  For a *real-valued* signal, $X(f)$ has conjugate symmetry,
meaning that $X(-f) = X^*(f)$, and so specifying $X(f)$ for
positive values of $f$ suffices.  In any case, the pictures
he is looking at are of $|X(f)|$ and $|\hat{X}(f)|$ which
are *even* functions of $f$, and so showing only the positive
axis saves space, though it *does* make the pictures look a 
bit lopsided since only half the lobe is shown at low frequencies.
For **complex-valued** signals, $X(f)$ does not have conjugate
symmetry and $|X(f)|$ need not be an even function of $f$
and so the whole axis would need to be shown.  But, the general
development above is still applicable, and we still need 
to sample at rate exceeding $b-a$ Hz, and it helps to keep in
mind that in this general case, each sample is actually two real
numbers, not one, since we are sampling a complex-valued signal.

Comment: Great answer. Hopefully we don't have anyone who wants to debate whether multiplication with a Dirac impulse train is a sensible model for sampling a signal discretely in time.

Comment: Thanks.  With regard to "sensible model for sampling a signal discretely in time", I suppose we could begin with a periodic function of $f$ as in $\hat{X}(f)$ above, and ask what is its complex exponential Fourier series which would be a bunch of points in time...

Answer (score 4):

For real-valued signals $f(t)$, the plots of $|\mathcal{F}\{f\}(x)|$ you show are symmetric across the real axis, because $\mathcal{F}\{f\}(-x) = \overline{\mathcal{F}\{f\}(x)}$ (the overbar to the right of the equality indicates complex conjugation).

This also explains the "flipping" you observe, I think. Imagine the top right subplot in your figure reflected across the x-axis; it's *that* spectrum which is being duplicated due to finite sampling.

EDIT:

$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}\{f\}(-x) &= \int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty} f(t) e^{-2\pi i t(-x)} dt
\\
&= \int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty} f(t) \cos(2\pi t(-x)) dt - i\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty} f(t) \sin(2\pi t(-x)) dt
\\
&= \overline{\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty} f(t) \cos(2\pi t(-x)) dt + i\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty} f(t) \sin(2\pi t(-x)) dt}
\\
&= \overline{\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty} f(t) e^{2\pi i t(-x)} dt}
\\
&= \overline{\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty} f(t) e^{-2\pi i tx} dt}
\\
&= \overline{\mathcal{F}\{f\}(x)}
\end{align*}$

Comment: Could you write out the proof of the duplication in rigorous mathematics?

Comment: All the pictures about the Nyquist sampling show the mirror symmetry. Does the Nyquist sampling theorem apply when the graph  in frequency domain isn't symmetric. More precisely does the Nyquist sampling theorem apply for complex signals $f(t)$ where $\mathcal{F}\{f\}(-x) = \overline{\mathcal{F}\{f\}(x)}$ is not true in general. And of course with the condition that $\mathcal{F}\{f\}(x)$ is zero outside a bounded set.